# Angular Material Dialog not closing after navigation

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-routing

I'm working on an application that shows an overview of entities in a datatable. Every entity has linked entities that are shown as 'xxx linked entities' in a column. When the user clicks on the value of that column, a material dialog opens showing the list of the linked entities. These are all links to other entities. Upon clicking one of these links, the correct page of the entity is shown, but the dialog doesn't close. I does close when using the back button. I am using the `closeOnNavigation` property.

Some example code:

In my main component:

```
public openDialog(entity: Entity) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EntityDialogComponent, {
        closeOnNavigation: true,
        data: {
            entity,
            otherEntities: this.getNameOfOtherEntities(),
        },
    });
}
```

Html of the dialog:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Linked {{otherEntities}}:</h1>
<mat-dialog-content>
<mat-list role="list">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let linkedEntity of entity.getProperty('linkedEntities')">
       <a class="m-link m--font-bold" [routerLink]="['/reporting/' + otherEntities, linkedEntity.id]">{{linkedEntity.name}}</a>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="cancel()">Close</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Dialog component:

```
@Component({
    selector: "entity-dialog",
    templateUrl: "entity-dialog.component.html",
})
export class EntityDialogComponent {

    public entity: Entity;
    public otherEntities: string;

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EntityDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: IDialogData,
    ) {
        this.entity = data.entity;
        this.otherEntities = data.otherEntities;
    }

    public cancel(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

}
```

On the side note:

When I'm on a specific entity page, and I click in a datatable to open a modal and click a link to another entity, the page scrolls to the top, the link in the browser changes to the correct link, but the page doesn't get refreshed for some reason.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi according to the docs it says: closeOnNavigation: Whether the dialog should close when the user goes backwards/forwards in history.

History Navigation Normally means browser back and forward buttons:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

What you could do in your scenario however is instead of routing directly from your html is create a function that will route after the dialog is closed this way you can ensure that you close the dialog first before initiating your navigation.

```
   <a class="m-link m--font-bold" (mousedown)="navigateToEntity($event)">{{linkedEntity.name}}</a>
```

Inside your component have something like

```
  navigateToEntity(event) {
    this.dialogRef.afterClosed.pipe(
      tap(() => this.router.navigate(['navigate to wherever'])),
      first()
    ).subscribe();
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

Hope this helps, i haven't worked much with Material Components but reading through some of the docs this is how i would implement it.

Comment: I was thinking about that solution as well, and I'll surely give it a try! Just not sure why Material didn't implement a regular close on navigation. Seems to be a useful thing to be!

Comment: Well at least they still give you the api's to make you own solution :)!

Comment: As this solves the problem of the dialog disappearing, it doesn't solve the problem that when the link in the browser changes and the page scrolls to the top automatically, the old content is still shown and not the new entity. If I refresh the page manually, the correct page gets shown

Answer (score 12):

When you navigate using `[routerLink]` directive or `router.navigate()` method of Angular's Router service within the MatDialog, the actual navigation happens. So we can just listen for router's changes and close the dialog.

In your `EntityDialogComponent` implement `ngOnInit` as following:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this._routerSubscription = this._router.events
     .pipe(
       filter((event: Event | RouterEvent) => event instanceof NavigationStart),
       filter(() => !!this.dialogRef)
     )
     .subscribe(() => {
       this.dialogRef.close();
     });
}
```

The code above closes a `dialogRef` when `NavigationStart` event is fired and there is an instance of the `dialogRef`.

P.S. Make sure that the `_routerSubscription` is unsubscribed.

Edit: Since Angular v16, `RouterEvent` must be typed as `Event | RouterEvent` because the Event union no longer contains RouterEvent. See https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=15.0-16.0.

Comment: Good point about unsubscribing, just to add on here:
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._routerSubscription.unsubscribe(); 
  }

Answer (score 7):

you can use this **matDialogClose** attribute.

```
<button mat-button matDialogClose>Cancel</button>
```

Comment: So simple, yet so effective and less noisy than the other solutions.

Comment: Yes, this solution works but it doesn't solve the problem, say the user opens the dialog and navigates to a different path typing the url... the dialog should automatically close. Your solution works only on the button

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem and I just fixed it now.

you need to subscribe router events after creating the dialogRef object. you can check the code

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyComponent, {
  width: '380px',
  height: '320px',
});
this.router.events
 .subscribe(() => {
   dialogRef.close();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There were no errors or warnings but `closeOnNavigation: true` started working for me only after adding these providers to the module with the dialog:

```
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy, APP_BASE_HREF } from "@angular/common";

...
    providers: [
        Location,
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }
    ]
...
```

I suspect that in my case this was because of using UI-Router and never initializing the built in Angular router before.