# Why run outside angular is implicitly called?

Tags: angular, zonejs

I had a similar issue with mat-dialog, I was not able to open/close it. What is interesting is that it works for about 20 minutes after I refresh the component.  But after that, it stops working.

I read this issue https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9875
and this https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9676
and this https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7550#issuecomment-345250406
and this StackOverflow answer: 
[Angular Material Dialog not closing after navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821766/angular-material-dialog-not-closing-after-navigation)

All suggested that *"Somehow, my code run outside angular zone, so I need to reenter the zone"*

Hence changing:

```
onButtonClick(){
   this.stopRecordingDialog.openDialog();
}
```

Somehow, wrapping the openDialog with ngZone.run() solve the issue.

```
onButtonClick(){
   this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.stopRecordingDialog.openDialog();
      });
}
```

But that's the part I don't understand. Why my code runs outside angular? I never explicitly call runOutsideAngular and the onButtonClick is neither inside an async callback.

In fact, onButtonClick is directly tied with a button element like this:

```
  <button mat-stroked-button (click)="onButtonClick()">
            <mat-icon>save_alt</mat-icon>
            Export
        </button>
```

So why my code runs outsideAngular ?

Comment: `<button mat-stroked-button type="button" ... >` Angular treats it like a submit form when you don't put `type="button"` Try it out and let me know. read this for more info https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html

Comment: I tried your idea. not working

Comment: the ngZone is used when an event happens outside Angular, e.g. you has a function in javaScript that change a variable in angular. So, I think that you has anything wrong in your code to not work (other use of ngZone is when we want not inmediatly response -e.g. when we are using a listener of window scroll-)

Comment: @TSR how are you sure that your code is run outside zone? Have you checked it with `NgZone.isInAngularZone()`?

Comment: Yes it returns false